# Information in the advice about previous advices

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Let's say we have a class with the following 2 methods:

```
public String getA() {
    return "A";
}

public String getAB() {
    return getA() + "B";
}
```

And I have an advice that **pointcuts both** methods:

```
@Before(...)    
public void beforePointCut() {

}
```

If you invoke method `getA()`, then pointcut is invoked **once**.
And when I invoke method `getAB()`, then the pointcut is invoked **twice**, because this method needs to invoke `getA()` internally too.
What **I want**  is to invoke advice only **once** when you invoke method `getAB()`. Is it possible? I don't want to split advice into two advices, because I have hundreds of methods that many of them invokes eachother.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need here is `cflowbelow(...)`. From the [AspectJ documentation](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html):

> `cflowbelow(Pointcut)`: Picks out each join point in the control flow of any join point P picked out by Pointcut, but not P itself.

You need to add `!cflowbelow(beforePointcut())` to your pointcut expression, similar to this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* YourClass.get*(..))")
public void beforePointcut() {}

@Pointcut("beforePointcut() && !cflowbelow(beforePointcut())")
public void beforePointcutOnlyOnce() {}

@Before("beforePointcutOnlyOnce()")
public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("before " + joinPoint);
}
```